# How do I get the current tag out of a taxonomy?

Tags: taxonomy, tags, terms

So I made a couple of custom taxonomies to add multiple categories to a page/project. (single-work.php) The default one (built in category) being `project type`, and the two new ones being `client` and `agency`.

Basically I use the same code for all three, but I just noticed that what it's doing for the two custom categories is basically reading out EVERY tag I've added to different projects, instead of only showing the tag that's selected for that specific page.

In other words, it's basically just showing every tag that can be found under the "Choose from the most used tags" area. Despite only a single tag being selected for each project.

I hope that was somewhat clear :)

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<?php $terms = get_terms( 'portfolio_tags_client' );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
        if ( is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) {
            continue;
        }
    echo 'Client: <a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>&nbsp;<br />';
    }
?>
```

And here's the taxonomy it's coming out of, if that helps:

```
register_taxonomy(
    'portfolio_tags_client',  //The name of the taxonomy. Name should be in slug form (must not contain capital letters or spaces). 
    'work', // Post type name
    array(
        'hierarchical'  =>  false,
        'label'         =>  'Clients', // Display name
        'singular_name' =>  'Client',
        'query_var'     =>  true,
        'rewrite'       =>  array(
        'slug'          =>  'client', // This controls the base slug that will display before each term
        'with_front'    =>  false // Don't display the category base before 
        )
    )
);
```

Does anyone know what it could be? I've spent way more time than I'd like to admit trying to fix this :)

**UPDATE** Fixed! Thanks so much for the help guys. I really appreciate it. Here's the final code:

```
<?php $post_tags = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_tags_client'); 
    if ($post_tags) {
        foreach($post_tags as $tag) {
        echo 'Client: <a href="'.get_tag_link($tag->term_id).'" title="'.$tag->name.'">'. $tag->name .'</a>&nbsp;<br />';
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is `get_the_terms()`. You can get custom terms for the current post by using the following code:

```
$post_tags = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_tags_client'); 
if ($post_tags) { ?>
    <div class="tags-div">
        <h3><?php _e( 'Tags', 'text-domain' ); ?></h3>  
        <div class="post-tags"><?php
            foreach($post_tags as $tag) {
                echo '<a href="'.get_tag_link($tag->term_id).'" title="'.$tag->name.'">'. $tag->name .'</a>'; 
            } ?>
        </div>      
    </div><?php 
}
```

This should be used in your `single.php` or the template that renders the content of your post. `get_the_term()` itself can be used anywhere, but since you have to pass the post's ID to it, you should use it in the proper template files.

Comment: It is indeed inside single-work.php that I'm working. I tried your code but it's still just blank. The entire echo disappears without even an error message.

Comment: @dem0n Use this and add the output to your question : `print_r($post_tags);`

Comment: What about `the_terms( $id, $taxonomy, $before, $sep, $after );` and skip the foreach loop ?

Comment: @birgire Sure, Is it possible to use `get_tag_link($tag->term_id)` as an argument too?

Comment: It should be included as it uses `get_the_term_list()`

Comment: I tried adding the print_r but still not seeing anything show up. Again no errors either. With the original code I just see a listing of all the tags inside the taxonomy, but at least I can see them :)

@JackJohansson So how would I go about implementing that in your example?

Comment: @dem0n Then I'm sure you are having a mistype or any problem other than this code. You aren't able to get any tags, please recheck for spelling errors.

Comment: So sorry I opened the wrong test project after implementing your code. It does work :D Thank you so much for your time and effort!

Comment: @dem0n You are welcome! That is why I always stop for a while after posting some comments, to make sure the OP investigates the code himself, something that I can't do remotely :)

Comment: Hehehe you are clearly experienced at this sort of thing ;) Apparantly I don't have enough points to upvote you, but I hope the accepting of the answer at least gives you something other than the satisfaction of helping out a guy who's spent half a day - pulling his hair out - on this thing :D (I wish I was kidding ...)

Comment: @dem0n That's alright mate. Everyone started with 1 reputation points, including myself :) Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behaviour of `get_terms()`. You can use [`wp_get_object_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms) instead

```
$terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'portfolio_tags_client' );
```

If you are inside the loop, you can use the following instead

```
$terms = wp_get_object_terms( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_tags_client' );
```

Comment: Hmm. When I do the following, it just disappears entirely:

`
 <?php $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'portfolio_tags_client' );
  foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
   $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
   if ( is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) {
    continue;
   }
  echo 'Client: <a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>&nbsp;<br />';
  }
 ?>
`

Comment: Well, do you have a `$post` variable in the scope? Depending on where your code is, try `get_the_ID()` instead

Comment: Sorry I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Where should I put that?

Comment: @dem0n Please see the update to my answer

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, kero, but now nothing is showing up. The entire echo has disappeared from the page. Not even an error message.

Comment: @dem0n Can you please specify (via editing your question), where exactly this code is run?

Comment: Updated the original question. Added update1. If that's relevant :) Sorry I'm still new here :)